# incorrect pixel offset when rasterizating 2d polygon compare to opengl standards

Tags: opengl

I am working on a bug fix related to opengl rasterization algorithms.

Basically, our software is using simple scan-line algorithm to rasterizating a image, but it seems there are some derivations to choose which pixel to fill.

Our 2d graphics render seems using different approach other than opengl standards, which as a result, the rasterized image file has incorrect sub-pixel offset than those software which implements opengl standards (like Maya, 3ds Max).

I read [opengl standards](http://www.opengl.org/registry/)  and its [docs](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec43.core.20130214.pdf) (chapter14). it's big and very vague in terms of implementation of the algorithm. Hope anyone can give me some suggestion where to go.

Our software are using scanline algorithms.

Comment: Maybe a long shot, but you can check OpenSource OpenGL implementations such as Mesa to check how it's done there.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL specification is purposefully vague on how an implementation should rasterize pixels, which both allows for alternative fragment generation (e.g., scan-line vs. implicit-plane checking for polygons), and avoids the snake pit of patent infringement.

However, if you're using an API for accelerating graphics rendering, why not use it as well for rasterizing your image using texture mapping?  Then both your image and any geometry will be rasterized in the same way (or at least using the same fragment generation implementation)?